# iptables -m recent не работает во время бот атаки

Tags: iptables

Я настроил правила iptables -m recent, они работают, если я их буду тестировать. Но во время крупной бот атаки они будто бы отключаются вообще.

Вот полный список правил INPUT:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1      100  5340 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 25565 match-set f2b-bungeecord-wrong-packet src reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
2        0     0 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 25565 match-set f2b-bungeecord-connection-login src reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
3     1885 97424 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 25565 match-set f2b-bungeecord-connection-ping src reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
4     1077 55500 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 25565 match-set f2b-bungeecord-antibot-filter src reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
5        0     0 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 25565 match-set f2b-bungeecord-wrong-packet src reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
6        0     0 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 25565 match-set f2b-bungeecord-connection-login src reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
7        0     0 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 25565 match-set f2b-bungeecord-connection-ping src reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
8        0     0 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 25565 match-set f2b-bungeecord-antibot-filter src reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
9        0     0 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 25565 match-set f2b-bungeecord-wrong-packet src reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
10     28M 4410M ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
11    401M   43G ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
12     351 19304 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:25565 state NEW recent: CHECK seconds: 1 hit_count: 3 name: minecraft side: source mask: 255.255.255.255
13      38  1976 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:25565 state NEW recent: CHECK seconds: 10 hit_count: 14 name: minecraft side: source mask: 255.255.255.255
14       0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:25565 state NEW recent: CHECK seconds: 60 hit_count: 70 name: minecraft side: source mask: 255.255.255.255
15    1070 64200 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:25565 state NEW recent: CHECK seconds: 300 hit_count: 100 name: minecraft side: source mask: 255.255.255.255
16   40420 2181K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:25565 state NEW recent: SET name: minecraft side: source mask: 255.255.255.255
17       0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:25565 flags:0x17/0x02 #conn src/16 > 200
18       0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:25565 flags:0x17/0x02 #conn src/24 > 50
19       0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:25565 flags:0x17/0x02 #conn src/32 > 8
20     426 22880 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 25565,25580,80,443,25569,8192 ctstate NEW
21       0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
22    2614 85222 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW
23   12870  772K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW match-set whitelist_ips src
24       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW match-set whitelist_nets src
25   11860  485K LOGGING-DROPPED  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

В частности те правила, которые не работают:

```
12     351 19304 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:25565 state NEW recent: CHECK seconds: 1 hit_count: 3 name: minecraft side: source mask: 255.255.255.255
13      38  1976 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:25565 state NEW recent: CHECK seconds: 10 hit_count: 14 name: minecraft side: source mask: 255.255.255.255
14       0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:25565 state NEW recent: CHECK seconds: 60 hit_count: 70 name: minecraft side: source mask: 255.255.255.255
15    1070 64200 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:25565 state NEW recent: CHECK seconds: 300 hit_count: 100 name: minecraft side: source mask: 255.255.255.255
16   40420 2181K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:25565 state NEW recent: SET name: minecraft side: source mask: 255.255.255.255
```

Настроено в 1 секунду не более 3 соединений, в 10 секунд не более 14 соединений. Сегодня случилась атака и вот, что я вижу в лог файле (это лог файл за пол секунды):

```
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #1/INFO]: [116.206.60.10] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #6/INFO]: [95.158.63.61] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #6/INFO]: [95.158.63.61] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #6/INFO]: [95.158.63.61] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #6/INFO]: [95.158.63.61] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #6/INFO]: [95.158.63.61] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #2/INFO]: [36.37.175.123] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #7/INFO]: [103.214.41.98] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #7/INFO]: [103.214.41.98] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #7/INFO]: [103.214.41.98] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #7/INFO]: [103.214.41.98] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #7/INFO]: [103.214.41.98] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #7/INFO]: [103.214.41.98] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #7/INFO]: [103.214.41.98] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #7/INFO]: [103.214.41.98] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #7/INFO]: [103.214.41.98] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #7/INFO]: [103.214.41.98] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #7/INFO]: [103.214.41.98] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #7/INFO]: [103.214.41.98] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #7/INFO]: [103.214.41.98] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #7/INFO]: [103.214.41.98] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #7/INFO]: [103.214.41.98] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #7/INFO]: [103.214.41.98] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #7/INFO]: [103.214.41.98] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #7/INFO]: [103.214.41.98] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #7/INFO]: [103.214.41.98] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #7/INFO]: [103.214.41.98] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #2/INFO]: [36.37.175.123] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #6/INFO]: [95.158.63.61] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #1/INFO]: [116.206.60.10] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #3/INFO]: [217.27.219.14] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #4/INFO]: [177.74.112.142] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #3/INFO]: [217.27.219.14] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #1/INFO]: [116.206.60.10] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #6/INFO]: [95.158.63.61] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #6/INFO]: [95.158.63.61] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #2/INFO]: [36.37.175.123] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #7/INFO]: [103.214.41.98] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #7/INFO]: [103.214.41.98] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #7/INFO]: [103.214.41.98] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #7/INFO]: [103.214.41.98] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #7/INFO]: [103.214.41.98] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #7/INFO]: [103.214.41.98] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #7/INFO]: [103.214.41.98] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #7/INFO]: [103.214.41.98] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #2/INFO]: [36.37.175.123] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #6/INFO]: [95.158.63.61] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #1/INFO]: [116.206.60.10] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #1/INFO]: [116.206.60.10] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #1/INFO]: [116.206.60.10] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #1/INFO]: [116.206.60.10] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #1/INFO]: [116.206.60.10] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #1/INFO]: [116.206.60.10] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #1/INFO]: [116.206.60.10] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #1/INFO]: [116.206.60.10] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #1/INFO]: [116.206.60.10] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #3/INFO]: [217.27.219.14] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #4/INFO]: [177.74.112.142] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #3/INFO]: [217.27.219.14] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #1/INFO]: [116.206.60.10] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #6/INFO]: [95.158.63.61] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #2/INFO]: [36.37.175.123] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #7/INFO]: [103.214.41.98] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #2/INFO]: [36.37.175.123] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #6/INFO]: [95.158.63.61] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #1/INFO]: [116.206.60.10] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #3/INFO]: [217.27.219.14] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #4/INFO]: [177.74.112.142] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #3/INFO]: [217.27.219.14] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #3/INFO]: [217.27.219.14] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #1/INFO]: [116.206.60.10] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #6/INFO]: [95.158.63.61] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #2/INFO]: [36.37.175.123] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #7/INFO]: [103.214.41.98] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #2/INFO]: [36.37.175.123] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #6/INFO]: [95.158.63.61] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #1/INFO]: [116.206.60.10] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #3/INFO]: [217.27.219.14] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #4/INFO]: [177.74.112.142] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #4/INFO]: [177.74.112.142] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #4/INFO]: [177.74.112.142] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #4/INFO]: [177.74.112.142] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #4/INFO]: [177.74.112.142] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #4/INFO]: [177.74.112.142] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #4/INFO]: [177.74.112.142] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #4/INFO]: [177.74.112.142] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #4/INFO]: [177.74.112.142] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #4/INFO]: [177.74.112.142] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #4/INFO]: [177.74.112.142] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #4/INFO]: [177.74.112.142] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #4/INFO]: [177.74.112.142] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #4/INFO]: [177.74.112.142] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #4/INFO]: [177.74.112.142] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #4/INFO]: [177.74.112.142] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #4/INFO]: [177.74.112.142] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #4/INFO]: [177.74.112.142] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #4/INFO]: [177.74.112.142] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #4/INFO]: [177.74.112.142] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #4/INFO]: [177.74.112.142] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #4/INFO]: [177.74.112.142] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #4/INFO]: [177.74.112.142] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #4/INFO]: [177.74.112.142] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #4/INFO]: [177.74.112.142] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #4/INFO]: [177.74.112.142] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #4/INFO]: [177.74.112.142] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #4/INFO]: [177.74.112.142] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #4/INFO]: [177.74.112.142] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #4/INFO]: [177.74.112.142] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #4/INFO]: [177.74.112.142] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #4/INFO]: [177.74.112.142] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #4/INFO]: [177.74.112.142] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #4/INFO]: [177.74.112.142] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #4/INFO]: [177.74.112.142] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #4/INFO]: [177.74.112.142] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #4/INFO]: [177.74.112.142] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #3/INFO]: [217.27.219.14] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #1/INFO]: [116.206.60.10] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #1/INFO]: [116.206.60.10] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #6/INFO]: [95.158.63.61] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #2/INFO]: [36.37.175.123] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #7/INFO]: [103.214.41.98] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #2/INFO]: [36.37.175.123] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #6/INFO]: [95.158.63.61] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #0/INFO]: [60.2.44.182] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #1/INFO]: [116.206.60.10] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
[13:21:33] [Netty Worker IO Thread #5/INFO]: [122.55.202.100] sent wrong Handshake packet. Junk??)
```

Почему не работали правила во время бот атаки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем выяснилось, что -m recent работает. Просто приложение зависает и логи пишет с задержкой, которые были накоплены за несколько секунд.

Так же хочу обратить внимание на hashlimit, он имеет такой же функционал, как и recent. В последствии я полностью перешел на hashlimit.